# magento2 custom option Compatible File Extensions set not required

Tags: magento2, custom-options

after migration my site,
i found one strenge issue that
when i saved product it not save,

after debbugging i found that

product has custom option of type file

and  Compatible File Extensions is required filed,

http://prntscr.com/izo2fm

how to set it to not required

Comment: Have someone found real fix for this problem?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136344)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You want to change only in Magento version 2.2 or greater.**

Create `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" type="vendor\module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" />
</config>
```

Please overwrite CustomOptions.php in your `vendor/module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php`

And find `getFileExtensionFieldConfig` function. remove this the code from that function,

```
'validation' => [
    'required-entry' => true,
],
```

After execute `php bin/magento cache:clean` and check your admin panel.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Editing directly a core file is not a good way. You should write a plugin or modify that option in the own class which will be injected in the global configuration (ui components pool of that form).

Comment: getFileExtensionFieldConfig()

Comment: Ill check in version 2.1.6 but its not required in than version,
so can you tell me in which version its change to required

Comment: Provide link if you have of change log

Comment: In Magento2.1.6, it is by default non-require.

Comment: You want to change only in Magento version 2.2 or greater.

Comment: It's useful or not for you? **@jigs**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75395/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-jigs-parmar).